# Iterate over object to create a new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, data-structures

This is the data that I'm getting that I want to manipulate

(This is only an extract of the overall object)

```
{
  A169: { t: 's', v: 'Umer', r: '<t>Umer</t>', h: 'Umer', w: 'Umer' },
  B169: { t: 's', v: 'Adnan', r: '<t>Adnan</t>', h: 'Adnan', w: 'Adnan' },
  C169: { t: 'asd', v: 'asd', r: 'asd' },
  D169: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'umer@asd.net',
    r: '<t>umer@asd.net</t>',
    h: 'umer@asd.net',
    w: 'umer@asd.net'
  },
  A170: { t: 's', v: 'Vitor', r: '<t>Vitor</t>', h: 'Vitor', w: 'Vitor' },
  B170: { t: 's', v: 'HAZIN', r: '<t>HAZIN</t>', h: 'HAZIN', w: 'HAZIN' },
  C170: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'NEUROBOTS',
    r: '<t>NEUROBOTS</t>',
    h: 'NEUROBOTS',
    w: 'NEUROBOTS'
  },
  D170: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'vitor.asd@asd.com.br',
    r: '<t>vitor.asd@asd.com.br</t>',
    h: 'vitor.asd@asd.com.br',
    w: 'vitor.asd@asd.com.br'
  },
  A171: { t: 's', v: 'Ziv', r: '<t>Ziv</t>', h: 'Ziv', w: 'Ziv' },
  B171: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'Lautman',
    r: '<t>Lautman</t>',
    h: 'Lautman',
    w: 'Lautman'
  },
  C171: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'BreezoMeter',
    r: '<t>BreezoMeter</t>',
    h: 'BreezoMeter',
    w: 'BreezoMeter'
  },
  D171: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'zivl@asd.com',
    r: '<t>zivl@asd.com</t>',
    h: 'zivl@asd.com',
    w: 'zivl@asd.com'
  }
}
```

And I'm looking to format it like this:

```
[
  {
    A169: { t: 's', v: 'Umer', r: '<t>Umer</t>', h: 'Umer', w: 'Umer' },
    B169: { t: 's', v: 'Adnan', r: '<t>Adnan</t>', h: 'Adnan', w: 'Adnan' },
    C169: { t: 'asd', v: 'asd', r: 'asd' },
    D169: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'umer@asd.net',
    r: '<t>umer@asd.net</t>',
    h: 'umer@asd.net',
    w: 'umer@asd.net'
  },
  {
    A170: { t: 's', v: 'Vitor', r: '<t>Vitor</t>', h: 'Vitor', w: 'Vitor' },
    B170: { t: 's', v: 'HAZIN', r: '<t>HAZIN</t>', h: 'HAZIN', w: 'HAZIN' },
    C170: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'NEUROBOTS',
    r: '<t>NEUROBOTS</t>',
    h: 'NEUROBOTS',
    w: 'NEUROBOTS'
  },
    D170: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'vitor.asd@asd.com.br',
    r: '<t>vitor.asd@asd.com.br</t>',
    h: 'vitor.asd@asd.com.br',
    w: 'vitor.asd@asd.com.br'
   },
  },
]
```

And so on...

As you can notice, the pattern is to group every "A,B,C,D" letter in objects that serve as indexes of the array

So far, I've tried something like this without getting the desired output

```
const arrayToGroup = [];

let firstName;
let lastName;
let company;
let email;

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(filtered)) {
  if (key.indexOf("A") > -1) {
    firstName = value.v;
  }

  if (key.indexOf("B") > -1) {
    lastName = value.v;
  }

  if (key.indexOf("C") > -1) {
    company = value.v;
  }

  if (key.indexOf("D") > -1) {
    email = value.v;
  }
  arrayToGroup.push({
    firstName,
    lastName,
    company,
    email,
  });
}

console.log(arrayToGroup);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
  {
    firstName: 'Abbas',
    lastName: undefined,
    company: undefined,
    email: undefined
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Abbas',
    lastName: 'AL ASMAR',
    company: undefined,
    email: undefined
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Abbas',
    lastName: 'AL ASMAR',
    company: 'QALEB STUDIO',
    email: undefined
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Abbas',
    lastName: 'AL ASMAR',
    company: 'QALEB STUDIO',
    email: 'abbas@asd.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Abdourazack',
    lastName: 'AL ASMAR',
    company: 'QALEB STUDIO',
    email: 'abbas@asd.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Abdourazack',
    lastName: 'ALI WABERI',
    company: 'QALEB STUDIO',
    email: 'abbas@asd.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Abdourazack',
    lastName: 'ALI WABERI',
    company: 'GREENTECH',
    email: 'abbas@asd.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Abdourazack',
    lastName: 'ALI WABERI',
    company: 'GREENTECH',
    email: 'asd@gmail.com'
  }, ...
```

Comment: The first two examples do not match the data presented in output. Moreover, the second example is invalid. Also, some of the data in the first two examples are incomplete and the keys make very little sense at all.

Comment: Also, each object has 5 key/values (except C169 inexplicably only has 3 key/values), yet the output only has 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you could get all the object keys, then you can reduce them and check if the current letter is "A", if so, create a new object with that key/object pair and push it to an accumulator. Otherwise, add the other key/object pairs to the newly created object:

```
let object = {};
Object.keys(o).reduce((p, c) => {
  if (c[0] !== "A") {
    object[c] = o[c];
  } else {
    object = { [c]: o[c] };
    p.push(object);
  }
  return p;
}, []);
```

Please check the snippet below:

```js
let o = {
  A169: { t: 's', v: 'Umer', r: '<t>Umer</t>', h: 'Umer', w: 'Umer' },
  B169: { t: 's', v: 'Adnan', r: '<t>Adnan</t>', h: 'Adnan', w: 'Adnan' },
  C169: { t: 'asd', v: 'asd', r: 'asd' },
  D169: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'umer@asd.net',
    r: '<t>umer@asd.net</t>',
    h: 'umer@asd.net',
    w: 'umer@asd.net'
  },
  A170: { t: 's', v: 'Vitor', r: '<t>Vitor</t>', h: 'Vitor', w: 'Vitor' },
  B170: { t: 's', v: 'HAZIN', r: '<t>HAZIN</t>', h: 'HAZIN', w: 'HAZIN' },
  C170: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'NEUROBOTS',
    r: '<t>NEUROBOTS</t>',
    h: 'NEUROBOTS',
    w: 'NEUROBOTS'
  },
  D170: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'vitor.asd@asd.com.br',
    r: '<t>vitor.asd@asd.com.br</t>',
    h: 'vitor.asd@asd.com.br',
    w: 'vitor.asd@asd.com.br'
  },
  A171: { t: 's', v: 'Ziv', r: '<t>Ziv</t>', h: 'Ziv', w: 'Ziv' },
  B171: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'Lautman',
    r: '<t>Lautman</t>',
    h: 'Lautman',
    w: 'Lautman'
  },
  C171: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'BreezoMeter',
    r: '<t>BreezoMeter</t>',
    h: 'BreezoMeter',
    w: 'BreezoMeter'
  },
  D171: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'zivl@asd.com',
    r: '<t>zivl@asd.com</t>',
    h: 'zivl@asd.com',
    w: 'zivl@asd.com'
  }
}

let object = {};
let result = Object.keys(o).reduce((p, c) => {
  if (c[0] !== "A") {
    object[c] = o[c];
  } else {
    object = { [c]: o[c] };
    p.push(object);
  }
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```